# Calling stored procedure from Entity Framework in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

[This is my output looks like...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUHj1.png)

and this is my backend

```
Beta_DatabaseEntities db = new Beta_DatabaseEntities();
table2 tb = new table2();

int ID;
string Name;
int Salary;

public void Entry()
{
        ID = Convert.ToInt16(id.Text);
        Name = name.Text;
        Salary = Convert.ToInt32(salary.Text);
}

private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Entry();
        tb.Id = ID;
        tb.Name = Name;
        tb.Salary = Salary;
        db.table1.Add(tb);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("GradeEntry "+)
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
create procedure GradeEntry
     (@ID int, @name nvarchar(50), @salary int)
As
Begin
    if(@salary >= 2500)
    Begin
        insert into Table2 values(@ID, @name, 'A+', @salary)
    End
    else if(@salary >= 1000)
    Begin
        insert into Table2 values(@ID, @name, 'A', @salary)
    End
    else if(@salary >= 500)
    Begin
        insert into Table2 values(@ID, @name, 'B', @salary)
    End
    else
    Begin
        insert into Table2 values(@ID, @name, 'Interni', @salary)
    End
End
```

I am working with Entity Framework but can't figure out how to call the stored procedure working in C#. I am using Visual Studio 2013

I just want to call the stored procedure from C# using Entity Framework.

Comment: Use `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC GradeEntry @ID, @name, @salary", id, name, salary)`, where `id`, `name` & `salary` are `SqlParameter`s, e.g. `var id = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int); id.Value = ID;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there with your `ExecuteSqlCommand`

You just need to add `EXEC`, then pass in the parameters:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC GradeEntry @ID, @name, @salary",
    new SqlParameter("@ID", ID),
    new SqlParameter("@name", Name),
    new SqlParameter("@salary", Salary),
)
```

[ExecuteSqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx) takes an array of object, as parameters.